# Shell script on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: bash, shell

Let me start by stating how little I know about all the programming stuff: Very very little.
I'm having a weird (to me) problem..

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdg-open #http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx

while [ 1 ]
do
xdtool key space
sleep 70
done
```

I can run the xdg open alone and it works, I can run the while portion alone and it works, but I cannot combine them..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: None that I see on the terminal.. The while part just never kicks in..

Comment: UPDATE: I've separated the 2 parts into 2 different scripts.. If I execute 1, than open a 2nd terminal and execute the other, all works fine. But if I add them both into another script in order to run them both, it only runs the 1st one, be it either the browser one or the key stroke..

Comment: `xdg-open` is executed in the foreground and the shell waits until that process terminates before continuing. Change that line to run in  the background instead using `xdg-open ... &`. Read more about job control [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html)

Comment: Ty, running the xdg open in the background did indeed fix the script.. Tyvm for the help, and sorry for anything..

Answer (score 0):

Adding my comment as an answer since it seems to solve to problem.

xdg-open is executed in the foreground and the shell waits until that process terminates before continuing. Change that line to run in the background instead using `xdg-open ... &`. Read more about job control [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html)